# horizontal scroll with ion-tabs icons

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, flexbox, ionic3

I want to use ion-tabs to get scollable tabs. but the tabs are getting shrinked but not scrolling horizontally. Here is the code: [toptabs](https://ionic-6amgve.stackblitz.io), [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6amgve?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

As it is a flex layout, i have tried using `white-space:nowrap` `flex-wrap:nowrap`

```
.tabbar{
    opacity:1;
    overflow-x:true;
    //width:auto;
}
.tab-button{
    flex:1 0 auto;
}
ion-tabs{
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

but nothing is working as expected. i want to make something like [this](https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins/ionic-2-scrollable-tabs)

can someone help? this is not a duplicate. please look at the code. i need tabs. Please understand before marking.

Comment: can you show your code on stackblitz?

Comment: sorry, attached https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6amgve?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html code link in the question as well.

Comment: I have seen that, its different interms of components used. its easier to work with tabs for my requirement and i need it the way in the last link i have posted in my question